Why I am getting this error when I run crewai.kickoff
I am getting this error when trying to run Crewai
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/PycharmProjects/crewaitest/crewaitest.py", line 92, in <module>
    result = crew.kickoff(inputs={'topic': 'Internal experts in mining technology'})
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/crew.py", line 526, in kickoff
    self._interpolate_inputs(inputs)
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/crew.py", line 1018, in _interpolate_inputs
    task.interpolate_inputs(
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/task.py", line 311, in interpolate_inputs
    self.expected_output = self._original_expected_output.format(**inputs)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'url'
Exception while exporting Span batch.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 490, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 466, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1095, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 730, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 909, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1041, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1319, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 667, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 474, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/util.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 490, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 466, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1095, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 730, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 909, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1041, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/Souradipta_Roy/anaconda3/envs/crewai/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1319, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

The code I am trying to execute is
from typing import List

from crewai import Agent, Task, LLM, Crew
from crewai.tools import tool

llm = LLM(
    model="gpt-4o",
    base_url="https://openai.prod.ai-gateway.quantumblack.com/0b0e19f0-3019-4d9e-bc36-1bd53ed23dc2/v1",
    api_key="5f393389-5fc3-4904-a597-dd56e3b00f42:7ggTi5OqYeCqlLm1PmJ9kkAVk69iWuWI"
)

ddagent = Agent(role="Assistant helping in executing due diligence steps",
                goal="""To help an user performing due diligence to achieve a specified task or multiple tasks. "
                      Sometimes multiple tasks need to be performed. The tasks need not be in a sequence""",
                backstory='You are aware about all the detail tasks of due diligence. You have access to the necessary content and best practices',
                verbose=True,
                memory=True,
                llm=llm
                )


@tool("get_experts")
def get_experts(topic: str) -> List[str]:
    """Tool returns a list of expert names."""
    # Tool logic here
    expert_list = []
    expert_list.append("Souradipta Roy")
    expert_list.append("Dushyant Agarwal")
    return expert_list


@tool("get_documents")
def get_documents(topic: str) -> List[str]:
    """Tool returns a list of document names."""
    # Tool logic here
    documents_list = []
    documents_list.append("document 1")
    documents_list.append("document 2")
    return documents_list


research_task = Task(
    description="""
        Respond withe appropriate output mentioned in the expected outputs when the user wants to create a survey 
        or wants to know anything about survey creation or survey analysis.
    """,
    expected_output="""
        Respond with the following:
        Great, to create surveys and drive analytics, there are currently two resources to utilize:
    a.    Survey Templates – Discover our collection of survey templates. The link for that tool is **https://privatecapital.mckinsey.digital/survey-templates**
    b.    Survey Navigator – Streamline survey creation, analysis, and reporting for client services team. The link for that tool is ** https://surveynavigator.intellisurvey.com/rel-9/admin/#/surveys**
    """,
    agent=ddagent,
    verbose=True
)

internal_experts_task = Task(
    description="""
        Respond with an appropriate sentence output listing the firm experts based on the topic mentioned.
    """,
    expected_output="""
        Respond with an appropriate sentence output listing the firm experts based on the topic mentioned.
        The firm experts are retrieved from the tool get_experts.""",
    agent=ddagent,
    tools=[get_experts],
    verbose=True
)

week_0_ramp_up_task = Task(
    description="""
        You are responsible for helping the user with Week 0 ramp up. There will be 6 sub-steps in this. If user chooses any of below sub-steps except document recommendations then provide details on respective option chosen.
    """,
    expected_output="""
        If user chooses any of below sub-steps except document recommendations then provide details on respective option chosen.

    a.    Get transcript for pre-reads or generate an AI Report –  “For transcript recommendations, please go to the Interview Insights (Transcript Library) solution to read up on transcripts relevant to the DD topic.” Here is the link for Interview Insights {url}. The Interview Insights platform includes AI-driven insights of thousands of searchable transcripts from prior ENS projects to generate AI Reports.
    b.    Get document recommendations – When this sub-step is chosen by user, do get_documents function calling to provide document recommendations based on the topic mentioned.
    c.    Look at past Due Diligences – “For past Due Diligence research, please go to the DD Credentials tools.” Here is the link for DD Credentials: **https://privatecapital.mckinsey.digital/dd-credentials** The DD Credentials tool can help you uncover past targets, outsmart competitors with our expertise, and connect with PE-qualified experts in seconds.
    d.    Review Past Interview Guides – “A comprehensive collection of modularized question banks for use in creating customer interview questionnaires.” Here is the link for the Interview Guides: **https://privatecapital.mckinsey.digital/interview-guide-templates**
    e.    Review Module Libraries – “Each Market Model folder includes a ppt overview, data sources, and an Excel model.” Here is the link for the Module Libraries: ** https://privatecapital.mckinsey.digital/market-models**
    f.    Private Capital Platform – “Resources and central hub for Private Capital and due diligence engagements.” Here is the link for the Private Capital Platform: **https://privatecapital.mckinsey.digital/**""",
    agent=ddagent,
    tools=[get_documents],
    verbose=True
)

crew = Crew(
    agents=[ddagent],
    tasks=[research_task, internal_experts_task, week_0_ramp_up_task],
    verbose=True
)
result = crew.kickoff(inputs={'topic': 'Internal experts in mining technology'})
print(result)

Getting this error in the second last line
Any help is appreciated.
